# Как вызвать событие изменения данных на поле, значение которого не изменилось?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

У меня есть компонент chart (график), в котором в реалтайме выводятся данные с сервера. Данные - это просто поле `value`, за которым  выставлено наблюдение через опцию `watch`. Если изменение произошло, то `value` кладется в массив chartData, после чего этот массив проецируется на график.

Проблема в том, что в `value` за последние N секунд могут последовательно  прийти одинаковые значения, и тогда реактивность не сработает, т.к. vue не сможет задетектить изменение `value`. В итоге, на графике не отобразится прямая за последние N секунд.

Можно ли как-то вызвать реактивность явно?

Есть идея отказаться от `watch` на `value` и использовать для этого уникальное поле (timestamp ответа, например), но из-за плохого знания vue, у меня нет уверенности, что `timestamp` и `value` будут обновляться одновременно.

Comment: `в реалтайме выводятся данные с сервера` - может, здесь перехватывать и обрабатывать?

Comment: Там несколько графиков, данные для которых загружаются одним запросом в родительском компоненте. Если загружать прям тут, то придется делать кучу маленьких запросов (для каждого графика + запрос с данными для родительского компонента)

Comment: не понимаю зачем вот эта связка value -> watch, если в месте присваивания значения value можно попросту вызывать то, что происходит в вотчере. Сделайте метод с функционалом watch: value() {...} и вызывайте его вместо this.value = "значение"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас подключение по реалтайму происходит через веб-сокеты, что логично, то `watch` вам совсем не нужен. У `WebSocket` есть слушатель, который срабатывает при получении сообщения. Вот в нем и обрабатывайте полученные данные — добавляйте в массив. А массив используйте для данных графика. Не забудьте про `computed`.

Пример работы сокетов:
https://learn.javascript.ru/websocket

```
// получение сообщения - отобразить данные в div#messages
socket.onmessage = function(event) {
  let message = event.data;

  let messageElem = document.createElement('div');
  messageElem.textContent = message;
  document.getElementById('messages').prepend(messageElem);
}
```

Если вы каждые N секунд шлете обычный get запрос на сервер, то прямо в этом методе сделайте аналогичную обработку – пуште данные в массив, а данные из массива получайте через `computed`.
https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html